# The animation does not end immediately in the half-second frame

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a sprite animation, everything works well, but when setting my own animation-fill-mode:forward, the animation only ends after some time on the last frame, and before that it flies away to an unknown place, filling the area with a white background, who can tell what this origin is, I will be very grateful.
It will also be great if someone else knows why when animating a sprite, when switching between step (), the animation jerks.

```
  background-image: url(../img/sprites/arrow.png);
  background-size: 510px 612px;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  animation: animator 5s steps(1) forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
@keyframes animator {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  0.23% {
    background-position: -51px 0px;
  }
  0.46% {
    background-position: -102px 0px;
  }
  0.69% {
    background-position: -153px 0px;
  }
  0.92% {
    background-position: -204px 0px;
  }
  1.15% {
    background-position: -255px 0px;
  }
  1.38% {
    background-position: -306px 0px;
  }
  1.61% {
    background-position: -357px 0px;
  }
  1.84% {
    background-position: -408px 0px;
  }
  2.07% {
    background-position: -459px 0px;
  }
  2.3% {
    background-position: -510px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: -51px -51px;
  }
  2.76% {
    background-position: -102px -51px;
  }
  2.99% {
    background-position: -153px -51px;
  }
  3.22% {
    background-position: -204px -51px;
  }
  3.45% {
    background-position: -255px -51px;
  }
  3.68% {
    background-position: -306px -51px;
  }
  3.91% {
    background-position: -357px -51px;
  }
  4.14% {
    background-position: -408px -51px;
  }
  4.37% {
    background-position: -459px -51px;
  }
  4.6% {
    background-position: -510px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: 0px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: -51px -102px;
  }
  5.06% {
    background-position: -102px -102px;
  }
  5.29% {
    background-position: -153px -102px;
  }
  5.52% {
    background-position: -204px -102px;
  }
  5.75% {
    background-position: -255px -102px;
  }
  5.98% {
    background-position: -306px -102px;
  }
  6.21% {
    background-position: -357px -102px;
  }
  6.44% {
    background-position: -408px -102px;
  }
  6.67% {
    background-position: -459px -102px;
  }
  6.9% {
    background-position: -510px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: 0px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: -51px -153px;
  }
  7.36% {
    background-position: -102px -153px;
  }
  7.59% {
    background-position: -153px -153px;
  }
  7.82% {
    background-position: -204px -153px;
  }
  8.05% {
    background-position: -255px -153px;
  }
  8.28% {
    background-position: -306px -153px;
  }
  8.51% {
    background-position: -357px -153px;
  }
  8.74% {
    background-position: -408px -153px;
  }
  8.97% {
    background-position: -459px -153px;
  }
  9.2% {
    background-position: -510px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: 0px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: -51px -204px;
  }
  9.66% {
    background-position: -102px -204px;
  }
  9.89% {
    background-position: -153px -204px;
  }
  10.12% {
    background-position: -204px -204px;
  }
  10.35% {
    background-position: -255px -204px;
  }
  10.58% {
    background-position: -306px -204px;
  }
  10.81% {
    background-position: -357px -204px;
  }
  11.04% {
    background-position: -408px -204px;
  }
  11.27% {
    background-position: -459px -204px;
  }
  11.5% {
    background-position: -510px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: 0px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: -51px -255px;
  }
  11.96% {
    background-position: -102px -255px;
  }
  12.19% {
    background-position: -153px -255px;
  }
  12.42% {
    background-position: -204px -255px;
  }
  12.65% {
    background-position: -255px -255px;
  }
  12.88% {
    background-position: -306px -255px;
  }
  13.11% {
    background-position: -357px -255px;
  }
  13.34% {
    background-position: -408px -255px;
  }
  13.57% {
    background-position: -459px -255px;
  }
  13.8% {
    background-position: -510px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: 0px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: -51px -306px;
  }
  14.26% {
    background-position: -102px -306px;
  }
  14.49% {
    background-position: -153px -306px;
  }
  14.72% {
    background-position: -204px -306px;
  }
  14.95% {
    background-position: -255px -306px;
  }
  15.18% {
    background-position: -306px -306px;
  }
  15.41% {
    background-position: -357px -306px;
  }
  15.64% {
    background-position: -408px -306px;
  }
  15.87% {
    background-position: -459px -306px;
  }
  16.1% {
    background-position: -510px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: 0px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: -51px -357px;
  }
  16.56% {
    background-position: -102px -357px;
  }
  16.79% {
    background-position: -153px -357px;
  }
  17.02% {
    background-position: -204px -357px;
  }
  17.25% {
    background-position: -255px -357px;
  }
  17.48% {
    background-position: -306px -357px;
  }
  17.71% {
    background-position: -357px -357px;
  }
  17.94% {
    background-position: -408px -357px;
  }
  18.17% {
    background-position: -459px -357px;
  }
  18.4% {
    background-position: -510px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: 0px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: -51px -408px;
  }
  18.86% {
    background-position: -102px -408px;
  }
  19.09% {
    background-position: -153px -408px;
  }
  19.32% {
    background-position: -204px -408px;
  }
  19.55% {
    background-position: -255px -408px;
  }
  19.78% {
    background-position: -306px -408px;
  }
  20.01% {
    background-position: -357px -408px;
  }
  20.24% {
    background-position: -408px -408px;
  }
  20.47% {
    background-position: -459px -408px;
  }
  20.7% {
    background-position: -510px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: 0px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: -51px -459px;
  }
  21.16% {
    background-position: -102px -459px;
  }
  21.39% {
    background-position: -153px -459px;
  }
  21.62% {
    background-position: -204px -459px;
  }
  21.85% {
    background-position: -255px -459px;
  }
  22.08% {
    background-position: -306px -459px;
  }
  22.31% {
    background-position: -357px -459px;
  }
  22.54% {
    background-position: -408px -459px;
  }
  22.77% {
    background-position: -459px -459px;
  }
  23% {
    background-position: -510px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: 0px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: -51px -510px;
  }
  23.46% {
    background-position: -102px -510px;
  }
  23.69% {
    background-position: -153px -510px;
  }
  23.92% {
    background-position: -204px -510px;
  }
  24.15% {
    background-position: -255px -510px;
  }
  24.38% {
    background-position: -306px -510px;
  }
  24.61% {
    background-position: -357px -510px;
  }
  24.84% {
    background-position: -408px -510px;
  }
  25.07% {
    background-position: -459px -510px;
  }
  25.3% {
    background-position: -510px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: 0px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: -51px -561px;
  }
  25.76% {
    background-position: -102px -561px;
  }
  25.99% {
    background-position: -153px -561px;
  }
  26.22% {
    background-position: -204px -561px;
  }
  26.45% {
    background-position: -255px -561px;
  }
  26.68% {
    background-position: -306px -561px;
  }
  26.91% {
    background-position: -357px -561px;
  }
  27.14% {
    background-position: -408px -561px;
  }
  27.37% {
    background-position: -459px -561px;
  }
  27.6% {
    background-position: -510px -561px;
  }
  27.83% {
    background-position: 0px -561px;
  }
  27.83% {
    background-position: -51px -612px;
  }
  28.06% {
    background-position: -102px -612px;
  }
  28.29% {
    background-position: -153px -612px;
  }
  28.52% {
    background-position: -204px -612px;
  }
  28.75% {
    background-position: -255px -612px;
  }
  28.98% {
    background-position: -306px -612px;
  }
  29.21% {
    background-position: -357px -612px;
  }
  29.44% {
    background-position: -408px -612px;
  }
  29.67% {
    background-position: -459px -612px;
  }
  29.9% {
    background-position: -510px -612px;
  }
  30.13% {
    background-position: 0px -612px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: right bottom;
  }
  to {
    background-position: right bottom;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet - which will include your sprite - so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: https://codepen.io/PavelAnt/pen/BaRRGdZ

Comment: While I have suggested a workaround in an answer to the problem as you have set it, are you happy with the 'flashing' between some frames - is it intentional?

Comment: No, I couldn't figure out the animation flickering either, I voiced it in the question. I thought that the frames change too slowly and because of this there is a flicker, but no, I changed the animation speed and keyframes. Do you have any options for what this might be related to?

Comment: I have tracked down the flickering and added a description of the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that some of the final frames of the animation keyframes definition 'miss' the background sprite. Hence there is a good proportion of the animation that looks blank.

This snippet takes a simple view of the solution, it cuts out the final frames of the animation, making sure that the penultimate frame shown and the last frame shown are the same, along with the animation-fill-mode being set to forwards, the animation final look persists.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container>.container__header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3% 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container>.container__header .figure-1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/GWedN7i.png);
  background-size: 510px 612px;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  animation: animator 30s steps(1) forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes animator {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  0.23% {
    background-position: -51px 0px;
  }
  0.46% {
    background-position: -102px 0px;
  }
  0.69% {
    background-position: -153px 0px;
  }
  0.92% {
    background-position: -204px 0px;
  }
  1.15% {
    background-position: -255px 0px;
  }
  1.38% {
    background-position: -306px 0px;
  }
  1.61% {
    background-position: -357px 0px;
  }
  1.84% {
    background-position: -408px 0px;
  }
  2.07% {
    background-position: -459px 0px;
  }
  2.3% {
    background-position: -510px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: -51px -51px;
  }
  2.76% {
    background-position: -102px -51px;
  }
  2.99% {
    background-position: -153px -51px;
  }
  3.22% {
    background-position: -204px -51px;
  }
  3.45% {
    background-position: -255px -51px;
  }
  3.68% {
    background-position: -306px -51px;
  }
  3.91% {
    background-position: -357px -51px;
  }
  4.14% {
    background-position: -408px -51px;
  }
  4.37% {
    background-position: -459px -51px;
  }
  4.6% {
    background-position: -510px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: 0px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: -51px -102px;
  }
  5.06% {
    background-position: -102px -102px;
  }
  5.29% {
    background-position: -153px -102px;
  }
  5.52% {
    background-position: -204px -102px;
  }
  5.75% {
    background-position: -255px -102px;
  }
  5.98% {
    background-position: -306px -102px;
  }
  6.21% {
    background-position: -357px -102px;
  }
  6.44% {
    background-position: -408px -102px;
  }
  6.67% {
    background-position: -459px -102px;
  }
  6.9% {
    background-position: -510px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: 0px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: -51px -153px;
  }
  7.36% {
    background-position: -102px -153px;
  }
  7.59% {
    background-position: -153px -153px;
  }
  7.82% {
    background-position: -204px -153px;
  }
  8.05% {
    background-position: -255px -153px;
  }
  8.28% {
    background-position: -306px -153px;
  }
  8.51% {
    background-position: -357px -153px;
  }
  8.74% {
    background-position: -408px -153px;
  }
  8.97% {
    background-position: -459px -153px;
  }
  9.2% {
    background-position: -510px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: 0px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: -51px -204px;
  }
  9.66% {
    background-position: -102px -204px;
  }
  9.89% {
    background-position: -153px -204px;
  }
  10.12% {
    background-position: -204px -204px;
  }
  10.35% {
    background-position: -255px -204px;
  }
  10.58% {
    background-position: -306px -204px;
  }
  10.81% {
    background-position: -357px -204px;
  }
  11.04% {
    background-position: -408px -204px;
  }
  11.27% {
    background-position: -459px -204px;
  }
  11.5% {
    background-position: -510px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: 0px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: -51px -255px;
  }
  11.96% {
    background-position: -102px -255px;
  }
  12.19% {
    background-position: -153px -255px;
  }
  12.42% {
    background-position: -204px -255px;
  }
  12.65% {
    background-position: -255px -255px;
  }
  12.88% {
    background-position: -306px -255px;
  }
  13.11% {
    background-position: -357px -255px;
  }
  13.34% {
    background-position: -408px -255px;
  }
  13.57% {
    background-position: -459px -255px;
  }
  13.8% {
    background-position: -510px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: 0px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: -51px -306px;
  }
  14.26% {
    background-position: -102px -306px;
  }
  14.49% {
    background-position: -153px -306px;
  }
  14.72% {
    background-position: -204px -306px;
  }
  14.95% {
    background-position: -255px -306px;
  }
  15.18% {
    background-position: -306px -306px;
  }
  15.41% {
    background-position: -357px -306px;
  }
  15.64% {
    background-position: -408px -306px;
  }
  15.87% {
    background-position: -459px -306px;
  }
  16.1% {
    background-position: -510px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: 0px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: -51px -357px;
  }
  16.56% {
    background-position: -102px -357px;
  }
  16.79% {
    background-position: -153px -357px;
  }
  17.02% {
    background-position: -204px -357px;
  }
  17.25% {
    background-position: -255px -357px;
  }
  17.48% {
    background-position: -306px -357px;
  }
  17.71% {
    background-position: -357px -357px;
  }
  17.94% {
    background-position: -408px -357px;
  }
  18.17% {
    background-position: -459px -357px;
  }
  18.4% {
    background-position: -510px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: 0px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: -51px -408px;
  }
  18.86% {
    background-position: -102px -408px;
  }
  19.09% {
    background-position: -153px -408px;
  }
  19.32% {
    background-position: -204px -408px;
  }
  19.55% {
    background-position: -255px -408px;
  }
  19.78% {
    background-position: -306px -408px;
  }
  20.01% {
    background-position: -357px -408px;
  }
  20.24% {
    background-position: -408px -408px;
  }
  20.47% {
    background-position: -459px -408px;
  }
  20.7% {
    background-position: -510px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: 0px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: -51px -459px;
  }
  21.16% {
    background-position: -102px -459px;
  }
  21.39% {
    background-position: -153px -459px;
  }
  21.62% {
    background-position: -204px -459px;
  }
  21.85% {
    background-position: -255px -459px;
  }
  22.08% {
    background-position: -306px -459px;
  }
  22.31% {
    background-position: -357px -459px;
  }
  22.54% {
    background-position: -408px -459px;
  }
  22.77% {
    background-position: -459px -459px;
  }
  23% {
    background-position: -510px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: 0px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: -51px -510px;
  }
  23.46% {
    background-position: -102px -510px;
  }
  23.69% {
    background-position: -153px -510px;
  }
  23.92% {
    background-position: -204px -510px;
  }
  24.15% {
    background-position: -255px -510px;
  }
  24.38% {
    background-position: -306px -510px;
  }
  24.61% {
    background-position: -357px -510px;
  }
  24.84% {
    background-position: -408px -510px;
  }
  25.07% {
    background-position: -459px -510px;
  }
  25.3% {
    background-position: -510px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: 0px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: -51px -561px;
  }
  25.76% {
    background-position: -102px -561px;
  }
  25.99% {
    background-position: -153px -561px;
  }
  26.22% {
    background-position: -204px -561px;
  }
  26.45% {
    background-position: -255px -561px;
  }
  26.68% {
    background-position: -306px -561px;
  }
  26.91% {
    background-position: -357px -561px;
  }
  27.14% {
    background-position: -408px -561px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -408px -561px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__header">
    <figure class="figure-1"></figure>
    <figure class="figure-2"></figure>
    <figure class="figure-3"></figure>
    <figure class="figure-4"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: there is also a marked flicker every so often. If we look at the keyframes settings we can see that the background image is moved between setting left 0 and left -510px. That is, it is moved along a row, then the top setting is incremented and left goes from 0 to -510px.

However, the natural dimensions of the image are 510x612 so at the end of each row the background image is moved completely out of the way and so a white frame appears, causing flickering.

This snippet takes the snippet above and alters the -510px to -459px - so the last frame on each row gets repeated. This is just to demonstrate that there is no flickering, but of course that last frame gets twice the exposure time of the other frames. For a 5s draw time this is not really noticeable but for a complete solution you need to recalculate the % points in the key frame so each takes 0.23 as now but with that repeated frame removed.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > .container__header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3% 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container > .container__header .figure-1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/GWedN7i.png);
  background-size: 510px 612px;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  animation: animator 5s steps(1) forwards;
  animation-fill-modes: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
@keyframes animator {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  0.23% {
    background-position: -51px 0px;
  }
  0.46% {
    background-position: -102px 0px;
  }
  0.69% {
    background-position: -153px 0px;
  }
  0.92% {
    background-position: -204px 0px;
  }
  1.15% {
    background-position: -255px 0px;
  }
  1.38% {
    background-position: -306px 0px;
  }
  1.61% {
    background-position: -357px 0px;
  }
  1.84% {
    background-position: -408px 0px;
  }
  2.07% {
    background-position: -459px 0px;
  }
  2.3% {
    background-position: -459px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  2.53% {
    background-position: -51px -51px;
  }
  2.76% {
    background-position: -102px -51px;
  }
  2.99% {
    background-position: -153px -51px;
  }
  3.22% {
    background-position: -204px -51px;
  }
  3.45% {
    background-position: -255px -51px;
  }
  3.68% {
    background-position: -306px -51px;
  }
  3.91% {
    background-position: -357px -51px;
  }
  4.14% {
    background-position: -408px -51px;
  }
  4.37% {
    background-position: -459px -51px;
  }
  4.6% {
    background-position: -459px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: 0px -51px;
  }
  4.83% {
    background-position: -51px -102px;
  }
  5.06% {
    background-position: -102px -102px;
  }
  5.29% {
    background-position: -153px -102px;
  }
  5.52% {
    background-position: -204px -102px;
  }
  5.75% {
    background-position: -255px -102px;
  }
  5.98% {
    background-position: -306px -102px;
  }
  6.21% {
    background-position: -357px -102px;
  }
  6.44% {
    background-position: -408px -102px;
  }
  6.67% {
    background-position: -459px -102px;
  }
  6.9% {
    background-position: -459px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: 0px -102px;
  }
  7.13% {
    background-position: -51px -153px;
  }
  7.36% {
    background-position: -102px -153px;
  }
  7.59% {
    background-position: -153px -153px;
  }
  7.82% {
    background-position: -204px -153px;
  }
  8.05% {
    background-position: -255px -153px;
  }
  8.28% {
    background-position: -306px -153px;
  }
  8.51% {
    background-position: -357px -153px;
  }
  8.74% {
    background-position: -408px -153px;
  }
  8.97% {
    background-position: -459px -153px;
  }
  9.2% {
    background-position: -459px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: 0px -153px;
  }
  9.43% {
    background-position: -51px -204px;
  }
  9.66% {
    background-position: -102px -204px;
  }
  9.89% {
    background-position: -153px -204px;
  }
  10.12% {
    background-position: -204px -204px;
  }
  10.35% {
    background-position: -255px -204px;
  }
  10.58% {
    background-position: -306px -204px;
  }
  10.81% {
    background-position: -357px -204px;
  }
  11.04% {
    background-position: -408px -204px;
  }
  11.27% {
    background-position: -459px -204px;
  }
  11.5% {
    background-position: -459px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: 0px -204px;
  }
  11.73% {
    background-position: -51px -255px;
  }
  11.96% {
    background-position: -102px -255px;
  }
  12.19% {
    background-position: -153px -255px;
  }
  12.42% {
    background-position: -204px -255px;
  }
  12.65% {
    background-position: -255px -255px;
  }
  12.88% {
    background-position: -306px -255px;
  }
  13.11% {
    background-position: -357px -255px;
  }
  13.34% {
    background-position: -408px -255px;
  }
  13.57% {
    background-position: -459px -255px;
  }
  13.8% {
    background-position: -459px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: 0px -255px;
  }
  14.03% {
    background-position: -51px -306px;
  }
  14.26% {
    background-position: -102px -306px;
  }
  14.49% {
    background-position: -153px -306px;
  }
  14.72% {
    background-position: -204px -306px;
  }
  14.95% {
    background-position: -255px -306px;
  }
  15.18% {
    background-position: -306px -306px;
  }
  15.41% {
    background-position: -357px -306px;
  }
  15.64% {
    background-position: -408px -306px;
  }
  15.87% {
    background-position: -459px -306px;
  }
  16.1% {
    background-position: -459px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: 0px -306px;
  }
  16.33% {
    background-position: -51px -357px;
  }
  16.56% {
    background-position: -102px -357px;
  }
  16.79% {
    background-position: -153px -357px;
  }
  17.02% {
    background-position: -204px -357px;
  }
  17.25% {
    background-position: -255px -357px;
  }
  17.48% {
    background-position: -306px -357px;
  }
  17.71% {
    background-position: -357px -357px;
  }
  17.94% {
    background-position: -408px -357px;
  }
  18.17% {
    background-position: -459px -357px;
  }
  18.4% {
    background-position: -459px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: 0px -357px;
  }
  18.63% {
    background-position: -51px -408px;
  }
  18.86% {
    background-position: -102px -408px;
  }
  19.09% {
    background-position: -153px -408px;
  }
  19.32% {
    background-position: -204px -408px;
  }
  19.55% {
    background-position: -255px -408px;
  }
  19.78% {
    background-position: -306px -408px;
  }
  20.01% {
    background-position: -357px -408px;
  }
  20.24% {
    background-position: -408px -408px;
  }
  20.47% {
    background-position: -459px -408px;
  }
  20.7% {
    background-position: -459px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: 0px -408px;
  }
  20.93% {
    background-position: -51px -459px;
  }
  21.16% {
    background-position: -102px -459px;
  }
  21.39% {
    background-position: -153px -459px;
  }
  21.62% {
    background-position: -204px -459px;
  }
  21.85% {
    background-position: -255px -459px;
  }
  22.08% {
    background-position: -306px -459px;
  }
  22.31% {
    background-position: -357px -459px;
  }
  22.54% {
    background-position: -408px -459px;
  }
  22.77% {
    background-position: -459px -459px;
  }
  23% {
    background-position: -459px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: 0px -459px;
  }
  23.23% {
    background-position: -51px -510px;
  }
  23.46% {
    background-position: -102px -510px;
  }
  23.69% {
    background-position: -153px -510px;
  }
  23.92% {
    background-position: -204px -510px;
  }
  24.15% {
    background-position: -255px -510px;
  }
  24.38% {
    background-position: -306px -510px;
  }
  24.61% {
    background-position: -357px -510px;
  }
  24.84% {
    background-position: -408px -510px;
  }
  25.07% {
    background-position: -459px -510px;
  }
  25.3% {
    background-position: -459px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: 0px -510px;
  }
  25.53% {
    background-position: -51px -561px;
  }
  25.76% {
    background-position: -102px -561px;
  }
  25.99% {
    background-position: -153px -561px;
  }
  26.22% {
    background-position: -204px -561px;
  }
  26.45% {
    background-position: -255px -561px;
  }
  26.68% {
    background-position: -306px -561px;
  }
  26.91% {
    background-position: -357px -561px;
  }
  27.14% {
    background-position: -408px -561px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="container__header">
            <figure class="figure-1"></figure>
            <figure class="figure-2"></figure>
            <figure class="figure-3"></figure>
            <figure class="figure-4"></figure>
        </div>
    </div>
```